# All Mongo documents with duplicated objects inside array

Tags: mongodb

Find documents with duplicated objects inside an array.

Some answers works just with array made of "basic type elements" (i.e. array of strings). Here I want to filter on certain objects fields

In example:

```
{ 
    "name": "1",
    "arr": [{ "type": "fruit", "name":"pear"},{ "type": "fruit","name":"banana"}]
},
{
    "name":"2",
    "arr": [{"type":"fish"}]
}
```

Given the above two documents, I want to retrieve just document 1, because it has 2 elements in the array that have the same type. (Of course I want all documents with such property, not just one)

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr:{
        $ne:[
            {
                $size:"$arr"
            },
            {
                $size:{
                    $setUnion:["$arr.type"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7b8546d76ccfa3cb0f133c"),
    "name" : "1",
    "arr" : [
        {
            "type" : "fruit",
            "name" : "pear"
        },
        {
            "type" : "fruit",
            "name" : "banana"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7b8546d76ccfa3cb0f133d"),
    "name" : "2",
    "arr" : [
        {
            "type" : "fish"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7b8546d76ccfa3cb0f133e"),
    "name" : "3",
    "arr" : [
        {
            "type" : "product",
            "name" : "watch"
        },
        {
            "type" : "product",
            "name" : "Pen"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7b8546d76ccfa3cb0f133c"),
    "name" : "1",
    "arr" : [
        {
            "type" : "fruit",
            "name" : "pear"
        },
        {
            "type" : "fruit",
            "name" : "banana"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7b8546d76ccfa3cb0f133e"),
    "name" : "3",
    "arr" : [
        {
            "type" : "product",
            "name" : "watch"
        },
        {
            "type" : "product",
            "name" : "Pen"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Query analysis:** We are filtering documents in which the size of `arr` is not equal to the count of unique `type` present in the `arr`